virtues other than the paramitas to practice in daily life
For some context, I have been practicing the paramitas in daily life—one each day, and then repeating them when they're done. But I felt the need to include a few other things that were missed in ancient times, but are probably important, at least in the beginning, in the modern world. So, I'm looking for a list of such virtues that I can add to my daily practice list. Few examples could be confidence non-deceitfulness fearlessness etc. Any suggestions ?

fearlessness, what do you mean? One can not practice fearlessness. It's a quality that arises out of others.

@Pycm correct! One can practice watching the fear though and truing to be free of it in that moment of fear (even though just a little)


So, I'm looking for a list of such virtues that I can add to my daily practice list.


Practice Panchasila (morality (sila parami))
Meththa meditation (loving kindness (metta parami))
Practice charity physically or mentally
don't ever lie (truthfulness (sacca parami) )


There are 10 Paramitha. Each of these Paramitha has 3 levels.

Parami (can be practiced in normal daily life)

Upaparami (sacrificing body parts while/for fulfilling Paramitha)

Paramaththaparami (sacrificing life while/for fulfilling Paramitha)


So, there are 30 Paramitha in total.
These 30 Paramitha covers all the good things one could do.
One could easily start at 1st level practicing this.
Kindness in speech is in Meththa Paramitha level one.
Strong determination, is in Adittana Paramitha level one.
Level one Paramithas are enough to reach Nirvana as an Arahant.
But to achieve the state of Lord Buddha or Pchchekabudda one has to complete all 30 Paramitha. (10 Paramitha with all 3 levels).


Overcoming fear a little,

It's building the confidence. Not a practice. It gets built as someone develops Knowledge(learning), Mindfulness, Sathi, Samadi, Meththa, Adittana, etc.

Confidence,

It's the same as overcoming fear.

non Seriousness/joy

Can someone develop/practice non-seriousness or joy? If someone does that, it's not real non-seriousness or joy.
(it's like, can someone be joyful/happy by thinking, I need to be happy now.? No. Right? True happiness arises out of inner fulfillment. Like, by reducing Thanha, developing Meththa, developing Upekka, developing Samadhi, etc.)
Actual non-seriousness and joy are not practiced. They get developed by others. (they just arise).
Non-seriousness and joy develop when someone practices Meththa Paramitha,  Dana Paramitha, Sila Paramitha, Wisdom Paramitha, Kindness Paramitha, Upekka Paramitha.
Even, if someone practices these Paramitha at level 1, non-seriousness and joy gets develop greatly.

So, there are some qualities that arise out of others. They are secondary qualities. That's why they are not included in 10 Paramitha by name(or in 30 Paramitha). But actually, they are included; that's because they get developed automatically while fulfilling others.


Read Paramitha Prakaranaya (පාරමිතා ප්‍රකරණය) for more information.

THE TEN PERFECTIONS (DASA PARAMI)
IN THERAVADA BUDDHISM



The 10 paramitas in Theravada is somewhat different from those in Mahayana. Traditionally, in Mahayana the 1st six parami are all that's needed for arhatship. The last 4 are more for the Bodhisattva path. It will be good to clarify the minimum needed for arhatship in Theravada tradition. It will also be more helpful if the link provided is in English.

I couldn't find that same pdf in English language, but it's the most complete and easily understandable reference I could find, that's in modern language style. That why it's there. I will post if I find good English reference. If you or anyone knows better references, please mention in comments. So, I can update / upgrade my answer.

Traditionally, in Mahayana the 1st six parami are all that's needed for arhatship. The last 4 are more for the Bodhisattva path. It will be good to clarify the minimum needed for arhatship in Theravada tradition As far as I know, there's no grouping in Theravada like that. May be, I don't know about it. Maybe. I will check.

Awesome, I find it hard to contemplate perfecting even one of the paramitas. Personally, I had been thinking about the qualities needed to be a good Buddhist practitioner. Such as for a non-Buddhist, what virtue(s) would made them suitable to be a good follower of the Dharma? I thought of 2 essential qualities.
First is honesty. I think this is the essential quality for being a good human being as well as a good Buddhist practitioner. Living in human societies with its intrigues, complexities and complications, one can easily get lost in all kinds of scheming, propaganda and biasness. Honesty in what one had done, spoken, seen, thought and intended is, therefore, crucial for walking a straight path. Without it, a person has an impaired sight with regards to cause and effect. Often, it is already hard to tease out the root causes to a certain effect i.e. why events and things go wrong (or right). This task is made almost impossible for someone who habitually lied to others and themselves. The insidious effect of lying also meant that these liars are often delusional and don’t even know their visions are already impaired. Pointing out their problems/weaknesses will only lead to vehement denials and hatred. It is very hard to help them. The Buddha himself remarked on this as well to Rahula (MN61).

In the same way, Rāhula, when anyone feels no shame in telling a deliberate lie, there is no evil, I tell you, he will not do.

Second is a willingness to put one’s beliefs to the test. Of course, verifications should not involve physical and material harm to oneself such as testing out the belief that one can fly by jumping off a cliff. But a willingness to verify beliefs time and again over a long period will eventually allow one to work out the cause and effect of certain things such as a virtue or vice. This requires keen observations and attention to details, alertness to changes and unbiased recollection of ourselves and others are all qualities needed to accomplish this task. At times, the verification need not be experimentation on oneself. It can be similarly accomplished through keen observation of others around us who possess such beliefs, virtues or vices. For example, we can pay attention and observe the lives of those who are habitual liars, drinkers or promiscuous in their relationships. As we compare their well-being financially, physically and mentally over the years and even decades, we can see clearly cause and effect in action. Ultimately, this quality allows one to develop pativedha or penetrating comprehension. With this, I believe we can pick up other skillful qualities and drop those unskillful ones for ourselves independently.
I believe these 2 qualities work hand-in-hand to make a better future for ourselves and those around us.

Great answer, thanks! While writing this question, I was thinking the same, that this has to be a personal thing. I totally agree On the other stuff as well. Today i Picked up a few qualities for myself : Overcoming fear a little, Confidence, Kindness in  speech, Strong determination, non Seriousness/joy and Mindful of mental images. I’m writing this year in order to Answer This question for future readers
Metta
